# Reading Http Get request from a inputstream and sending it to the host. using sockets

Tags: java, http, sockets, io, network-programming

i have this assignment where i am supposed to write a proxy server that uses java sockets to handle get requests from a client. I am now stuck and have been looking all over google to find the answer but without success.

Christoffers solution helped my with my first problem. Now that i have updated the code this is what i am using.

The problem is that it only downloads parts of most webpages before it gets stuck on sending the packets back to the client loop. At the moment I cant explain why it is behaving the way it is.

```
public class MyProxyServer {  
    //Set the portnumber to open socket on
    public static final int portNumber = 5555;  

    public static void main(String[] args){  
//create and start the proxy
MyProxyServer myProxyServer = new MyProxyServer();  
myProxyServer.start();  
}  
public void start(){  
System.out.println("Starting MyProxyServer ...");  
try {  
    //create the socket 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(MyProxyServer.portNumber);  

    while(true)
    {    
        //wait for a client to connect
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  

        //create a reader to read the instream
        BufferedReader inreader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));  

        //string builder for preformance when we loop over the inputstream and read lines
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String host = "";


        for (String buffer; (buffer = inreader.readLine()) != null;) {
        if (buffer.isEmpty()) break;
        builder.append(buffer.replaceAll("keep-alive", "close"));
        if(buffer.contains("Host"))
            {
            //parse the host
            host = buffer.replaceAll("Host: ", "");
            }
        System.out.println(buffer);
        }


        String req = builder.toString();
        System.out.println("finshed reading \n" + req);
        System.out.println("host: " + host);


        //new socket to send the information over
        Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), 80);

        //printwriter to send text over the output stream
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()); 

        //send the request from the client
        pw.println(req+"\r\n");
        pw.flush();

        //create inputstream to receive the web page from the host
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        //create outputstream to send the web page to the client
        BufferedOutputStream outbuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesread;

        //send the response back to the client
        while((bytesread = in.read(bytebuffer)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(bytesread);
        outbuffer.write(bytebuffer,0, bytesread);
        outbuffer.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("done sending");

        //close the streams
        inreader.close();
        s.close();
        pw.close();
        outbuffer.close();
        in.close();
    }


} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();
}  catch(RuntimeException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

If anyone could explain to me why i cant get it working correctly and how to solve it I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First blush is that you're using a PrintWriter which is character based, you'll need a byte based stream for images

Comment: Thanks for giving me tips! I have been looking around some now without finding a sollution to the problem you discribe. Without using a HttpURLConnection java class. What should i use to send the requests if a Printwriter does not work?

Comment: Stay away from `Reader` and `Writer`, use their corresponding `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. As @karakuricoder says, `Reader` and `Writer` are for characters, while `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are for bytes. When you use an `InputStreamReader` or `OutputStreamWriter` without specifying an encoding, you're corrupting your bytes by converting them according to the platform default encoding, which is for all intents and purposes a global random variable. You should never not specify an encoding when using them, and in this case you should only pass the headers through them.

Comment: To clarify: The headers are character data, and you should *maybe* use Readers and Writers for those, and if you do, you definitely need to specify the encoding you're using, which for HTTP is ISO-8859-1 if i recall correctly. The rest of the data should be treated as just bytes and passed through as is, using InputStream/OutputStream.

Comment: Thanks for the help Christoffer! This was very helpfull! i have changed the readers/writers that i used to recive the data from the server and sending it back to the client and it solved the initial problem.

Comment: You need to look up the HTTP 1.1 RFC. There is a `CONNECT` command that you have to act on and reply to. Just scanning headers for Host: is not correct: you shouldn't do it. The rest of writing a proxy is basically just copying bytes and reacting correctly to EOS conditions on each side. You shouldn't have to mess with `connection: keep-alive/close` for example.